# Regex also capture everything besides capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have come up with a javascript regex that captures Street Numbers from an address string:

```
(\d+-\d+|\d+\/\d+|\d+\w{0,2})
```

now I would like to capture also the rest of the string (before and after) in additional capture groups.
Formats that I will test against:

```
Streetname 23
Streetname 12-15
Streetname 12/15
Streetname 13c
Streetname 34 with additional text
```

Comment: You may use: `/^(.*?)\b(\d+(?:[\/-]\d+|\w{0,2}))(.*)$/`

Comment: You could also replace the street numbers with an empty string and then proceed with the other capture groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with 3 captured groups:

```
/^(.*?)\b(\d+(?:[\/-]\d+|\w{0,2}))(.*)$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WbbvUu/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(.*?)`: Match 0 or more characters at start (non-greedy) in 1st capture group
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(\d+(?:[\/-]\d+|\w{0,2}))`: Match street no in 2nd capture group
- `(.*)`: 3rd capture group to match remaining text till end
- `$`: End

**Flags**

- `g`: Global match; find all matches rather than stopping after the first match
- `m`: Multiline